# find maximum value in one element of dictionary in c++

Tags: c++

I have a map of lists and I want to find the maximum value in the list related to every key. for example, map[0](the lists related to the key 0) consists of 3 tuples {1,2},{4,2},{4,8} I want to find max{2,2,8}=8 in this list of dictionary. then I want to repeat it for every key in the dictionary. the code I wrote is as follow:

```
std::map<int, list<std::tuple<int, int> >> map1;

list<std::tuple<int, int>> t = list<std::tuple<int, int>>();
t.push_back(make_tuple(4, 3));
t.push_back(make_tuple(2, 6));
map1[0] = t;

t.push_back(make_tuple(5, 6));
map1[1] = t;
```

how can I find the maximum value in the map1[0] and map1[1] separately?

Comment: Iterate through the map and call `max_element` on each list?

Comment: I tries it, but it finds the maximum value according to the first elements of list. I want to find the list that the second value is maximum in

Comment: You need to pass in a custom comparator if you only want to check the last element of the `tuple`.

Comment: I do not know how to do it. would you please introduce me a reference about it?